# It is possible to access a parent entity through navigation properties in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Consider the following:

`TestimonialsPageModel (parent)
      // Navigation property:
   -  public virtual ICollection<TestimonialModel> TestimonialModel { get; set; } 
   - // Other properties`


`TestimonialModel (child)
     // Navigation property:
  -  public TestimonialsPageModel TestimonialsPageModel { get; set; }
  -  public int TestimonialsPageId { get; set; }
  - // Other properties`

If I want to get the Testimonials for the TestimonialsPage (Parent -> child) I know I can just do:

`TestimonialsPageModel.TestimonialsModel.ToList();`

But can I do it the other way round ?

`TestimonialsModel.TestimonialsPageModel.FirstOrDefault();`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you load the instances.

```
db.TestimonialsPages.Include(x => x.TestimonialModel)
```

...vs...

```
db.TestimonialsModels.Include(x => x.TestimonialsPageModel)
```

Comment: Yea thanks, I meant without using the Include function. Just traversing straight as in my example.

Comment: You can do it without `.Include`, but you need explicitly ask for it in the `Select`